# how to set an alarm in java

Tags: java, desktop, alarm

I'm currently trying to use java to open my default web browser to a YouTube video at a specific time I enter into the program (To make an alarm of sorts)

Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.io.IOException;


public class YtAlarm
{
    int hr;
    int min;
    public YtAlarm(int hours, int minutes) //constructor 
    {
        hr = hours;
        min = minutes;
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException //main method
    {
         String url = "https://www.youtube.com"; //link to open once alarm goes off

         YtAlarm ytalarm = new YtAlarm(15, 20); //sets alarm to go off at 3:20 PM
         long alarm1 = ytalarm.convertTimeToMilli(); //converts alarm time to ms


        do //checks what time it is on each itteration and once alarm1== curent time, opens yt video
        { 
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() == alarm1)
             {
                if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
                {
                     Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(url));
                }
             }
         } 
         while (System.currentTimeMillis()!= time); 
    }

    public long convertTimeToMilli() //method to convert alarm time from hours and minutes to ms
    {
         long milli = (60000*min) + (3600000*hr);
         return milli;
    }
}
```

This code compiles with no errors but doesn't function properly. It doesn't open the link I have entered when the current time matches the time I entered into the constructor. Does anyone know how I can change my code so that it functions the way I intend for it to?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: You're effectively converting `hr` and `min` to a instant like `1970/Jan/01 hr:min:00`, as in `milli` is *way* in the past. You need to take the year/month/day into account too.

Comment: Any reason not to use [`Timer` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)?

Comment: That busy-wait loop will keep your CPU busy before the alarm is triggered. Would be better to use `Timer` or `Thread.sleep()` to check the time with some reasonable interval.

Comment: `public YtAlarm(int hours, int minutes) //constructor` The most valueable comment I ever seen :)

Comment: @AndyTurner That would make sense. I'll give that a shot when I get the chance and I'll update. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

first compare your alarm1 value with System.currentTimeMillis() value you will know the reason. Actually System.currentTimeMillis() give you total millisecond from 1st Jan 1970 till now and yours is total milliseconds from midnight to till that time(15:20).
You can use 

`LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
   int hour=now.getHour();
   int minute=now.getMinute();`

after that compare hour with hr as well as minute with min.

Comment: I would recommend you to create more descriptive answers. Piece(s) of code can help understand the solution pointed by you. Don't forget about grammar and friendly formatting. Good luck!